# HighCharts:the data from database are not same with the x-axis(month)

Tags: php, mysqli, highcharts

I'm doing a column bar charts with the x-axis from Jan to Dec and y-axis is number of people.

I have table_name called `report_info_notice` and a `column_name` called `date_notification.`

The `date_notification` consists of 4 data: `2015-12-22, 2015-12-15 ,  2015-06-17 , 2015-02-18.`

I retrieve the data from database but the data plot at Jan,Feb...

It didn't plot at the right position like `2015-12-15` should be plot at Dec.
I already spent for the whole day to try to solve this but still can't. Can anyone guide me?

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <?php include_once 'mysql_connect.inc.php'; ?>
    <html>
     <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        ${demo.css}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
         chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Infected People(Month)'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [

                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ],
            crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Number of people'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {

            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f}</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Dengue Fever',
            data: [

            <?php
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","userdatabase");
            $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT YEAR(date_notification), MONTH(date_notification) AS MONTH, COUNT(*) AS count FROM report_info_notice GROUP BY YEAR(date_notification), MONTH(date_notification)");
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            ?>
            [<?php echo $row['count'] ?>],
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            ]

        }, {
            name: 'Dengue Haemorrhagic Fever',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

        },]
     });
    });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="highcharts/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="highcharts/js/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="highcharts/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```